# \frac overlapping in nested itemize in beamer

Tags: beamer

When I try this MWE, the fractions are overlapping:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}
\item 
\begin{itemize}
\item $\frac{5}{8}$
\item $\frac{5}{2}$
\end{itemize}

\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What is the best way to fix this problem?

Comment: Try `\setlength{\itemsep}{1ex}` inside itemize enviroment or `\item $\frac{5}{8}$\\[1ex]`

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend to switch to `xfrac` fractions here. If you do not like this, you will have to stretch the vertical space between your items. I also added the two ideas mentioned in comment by cornelius.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xfrac}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item 
        \begin{itemize}
            \item $\sfrac{5}{8}$
            \item $\sfrac{5}{2}$
        \end{itemize}
        \item 
        \begin{itemize}
            \item $\frac{5}{8}$\\[0.6ex]
            \item $\frac{5}{2}$
        \end{itemize}
        \item 
        \begin{itemize}
            \setlength{\itemsep}{0.6ex}
            \item $\frac{5}{8}$
            \item $\frac{5}{2}$
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For completeness, I think you can add as option the possible solution with the templates `itemize/enumerate body begin` and `itemize/enumerate body end`.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Please feel free to edit. Marked it CW. I am not using Beamer and don't want to write something wrong here...